# Using gradle, testNG is scheduling tests in parallel inefficiently

Tags: selenium, gradle, parallel-processing, testng

this is my first question so I hope to be as concise as possible.

I'm currently using gradle in order to build and run about 1.7k tests.  The test's are being run by using the command "useTestNG { excludeGroups 'functional,integration,performance,serialization,endtoend,version'}".

The issue I'm having with this is that when forking up 5 instances of chrome, they start off all running the tests and then a bit of the way through 4 will be running, then 3, then two, then 1.  The idea here is that the workload towards the end of testing is being split inefficiently.  Ideally, if all 5 instances would run the duration of the test period, then the time it takes to execute all the tests could dramatically decrease.

I found that TestNG has an option "parallel" which can be passed to in which tells it how to split up its tests.  My last attempt at speeding things up was by adding this option;

useTestNG { excludeGroups 'functional,integration,performance,serialization,endtoend,version' parallel 'instances'}

This didn't seem to do the trick though.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: Did you try using the Gradle `Test` tasks's `maxParallelForks` option?

http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:maxParallelForks

Comment: Yup, I'm already using that. That determines how many fork there will be.  But it does not determine how the tests will be getting split up.  Thanks for the input though :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mulitple "testng.xml" files? If so, that is more than likely the cause. Each xml file finishes before the next one will start.

Comment: Hey Shawn Knight, I don't believe that I'm using xml's for test cases.  The test cases are being pulled in from a folder containing a bunch of .java files.  I guess it's using the Junit API because in each of those files, there are 1 or more @Test preceding different functions.

Comment: I am confused by your statement, "it's using the Junit AP", when you are calling useTestNG in your Gradle script - Are trying to use both? Assuming you are using TestNG, how are you paralleling your tests, at the class, test, or method level?

Comment: Right now I'm paralleling tests at the "tests" level.  This can be seen below:
`task honorTest(type: Test, dependsOn: 'seleniumBaseTask') {
 configure seleniumTestConfiguration
    description 'Runs partial Selenium Functional Tests'
    useTestNG { excludeGroups 'functional,integration,performance,serialization,endtoend,version' parallel 'tests'}
}`

HonorTest is a test suite that run based on tests specified for that suite. For Example:
 @Test(groups={"honor"})
    public void multipleFormatting0() {
        openWebsite(DOCUMENT);
}

Comment: And what happens when you parallel with methods?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference.  I've tried "methods", "tests", and "instances" and they are all taking roughly 1 hour to complete.  I'm running it again to see if towards the end, one selenium instance is handling all of the tests instead of 5 as it should be.